# Discord does not respond to commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

It is a simple command but my bot is not responding when I ask it. It has administrator priviledges so it should respond. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```js
const {
    Client,
    Intents,
    Message
} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]
});
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot ${client.user.tag} foi carregado em ${client.user.size} e esta online!`);
    client.user.setGame(`Eu estou em ${client.guilds.size} servidores`)
});

client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log(`O bot entrou nos Servidor: ${guild.me} (ID: ${guild.id}). QTD mebros: ${guild.memberCount} `);
    client.user.setActivity('YouTube', {
        type: 'WATCHING'
    });
});

client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    console.log(`O bot foi removido do serivdor: ${guild.name} (ID: ${guild.id})`);
    client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`)
})

client.on("menssage", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (menssage.channel.type === "dm") return;

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const comando = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (comando === "ping") {
        const m = await message.channel.send("Ping?");
        m.edit(`Pong a latencia e ${m.createdTimesTamp - message.createdTimesTamp}ms. `)
    }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Keep in mind that it's easier for others to help you out if you paste the error in as text, rather than linking to an image of it.

Comment: The error is very clear. `client.user.setGame` is not a valid function

Comment: ok tks, would you know why he is not responding when I request a command such as ping ?

Comment: The event you should be listening for is `"message"`, not `"menssage"`.

Comment: I made the adjustments but it still doesn't return anything

Comment: Looks like you are using discord.js v13. The `message` event is deprecated, use `messageCreate` instead. Also you are missing the `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES` intent to receive the event.

Comment: Welcome Del, the best way to let other developers to help you is to give them a maximum of information about the question what happened what you tried and what is the actual Error

Answer (score 1):

The function `setGame` doesn't exists, you need to change it to

```js
client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`, { type: 'PLAYING' })
```